# Kinesis firehose to s3 JSON objects not delimited

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a data pipeline that is something like this : `Kinesis Firehose -> S3`

When I use the glue crawler to create an Athena table over this data the table only reads some of the actual rows. The data in the file looks like this :

```
{row1}{row2}{row3}{row4}\n
{row5}{row6}{row7}
```

If I modify the data to have a newline after each row the Athena table will read the data properly. What I am wondering is how other people have solved this problem.

The solution I am considering is to write a python lambda function that takes care of the `\n` new line delimiter for the rows. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: did you find a suitable solution to this problem?

Comment: I was told by AWS support to add the new line after each JSON row.

Comment: are you writing to firehose through api gateway?